# Importing classes from other projects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, import

So I have a Project1 with class A. I have Project2 with class B. How do I import class A to B without having to create a new class in the Project2 etc. I get this has to do with the build path, but how do I add so I can write something like
`import Project1/A;`
Along with my JRESL imports?

Comment: make your ```Project1``` as jar file and add it to build path. in ```Project2 ``` just call ```class A``` as normal import.

Comment: That's not about Eclipse (the editor) but about Java and dependencies. You can use classes coming from another jar into your project as soon as you add a dependency from Project2 to Project1. That depends on your dependency management system (Maven? Gradle?...)
P.s. there is a way to "add to classpath", but I wouldn't suggest you to do that cause it wouldn't work in a production system (if you have a dependency on something, you should make it explicit)

Comment: In Project2 go to _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab _Projects_, click _Add..._ and select Project1. With that you can use class A of package `com.example.project1` (better do not use the default package when using more than one project): `import com.example.project1.A;`

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Project1` as a jar file and import that into the build path of `Porject2` . Then you can call `class A` in class `B` as usual .

Note : Above approach is good if you are doing it once . If `Project 1` changes often, this method can be tiresome . Each time you have to make `Project1`  as jar file and import it .

> If `Project1` changes frequently, do the following.

Right click on Project2, then click on Properties. In the dialog that comes up, select Java Build Path, and then click on the Projects tab. There, add Project1 to the build path.

If Project2 is a web app, you need to make sure your Deployment Assembly (same Properties UI) has Project1 there as well.